# While loop that reads a logfile and completes when the string "shutdown complete" is present

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script for my company that takes down relevant services on a server when it is being patched.

I'm trying to create a while loop in the script that tails a jboss logfile, and completes when "shutdown complete" is present.

Here was my idea for how to do this:

```
  while [$SHUTDOWNSTATUS = ]; do
  tail -f serverlog | grep 'Shutdown complete'
  SHUTDOWNSTATUS='Shutdown complete'
   done;
```

I guess it's not really the original idea. This was what I got to before I got stuck. The loop never completes because the tail never stops.

I was doing some research about the "read" command. Would this work better for my needs?

Comment: You need a space between `[` and `$SHUTDOWNSTATUS` and something on the right-hand side of the `=` (even just an empty string `''`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like there should be a better idea than this but I can't think of one offhand.

Just loop (with a sleep delay) until `grep` on the file returns true. (Unfortunately this means re-reading the entire file each loop but avoiding that is more complicated.)

```
while ! grep -q 'Shutdown complete' serverlog; do
    sleep 5s
done
echo 'Shutdown complete'
```

Comment: While this isn't the most elegant solution, it is what I ended up implementing. A big part of me writing this script, is also understanding what it's doing. The other answers don't make sense to me. They give me things to look into, but I want to implement something that I personally understand.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to redirect the log file to a file descriptor and then read the file descriptor until "Shutdown complete" appears in the log file. Then terminate the loop. An example is:

```
#!/bin/bash

lfn=${1:-dat/jboss.log}     # logfile (default: dat/jboss.log for test)

## test log is readable
[ -r "$lfn" ] || {
    printf "error: file '%s' is not readable.\n" "$lfn"
    exit 1
}

## redirect log to fd 3 and read until "Shutdown complete"
while :; do

    read -r -u 3 line
    if [[ $line =~ "Shutdown complete" ]]; then
        sdstatus=complete
        break
    else
        sleep 5 # adjust sleep as needed
    fi

done 3< "$lfn"  # temporary redirection of $lfn to 3

printf "Shutdown %s\n" $sdstatus

exit 0
```

**example**

```
$ echo "line 1" > dat/jboss.log

$ cat dat/jboss.log
line 1

$ bash shutdown.sh &
[1] 17446

$ echo "patch applied, Shutdown complete" >> dat/jboss.log
$ Shutdown complete

[1]+  Done                    bash shutdown.sh

$ cat dat/jboss.log
line 1
patch applied, Shutdown complete
```

**Note:** this is a Bash solution due to the use of the substring comparison operator `=~`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid re-reading the log file (or at least doing it as quickly as possible) is to remember the file size from the last loop iteration, and skip that many bytes:

```
while :; do
    size=$(stat -c "%s" serverlog)
    new_text=$(dd if=serverlog bs="$old_size" skip=1 2>/dev/null)
    if [[ -n $new_text ]]; then
        echo "${new_text%%Shutdown complete*}
        [[ $new_text == *"Shutdown complete"* ]] && break
        old_size=$size
    fi
    sleep 0.5s
done
```